# dynamic centered alignment of a ul with css

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

i am pulling data from database that prints in a ul li format. since data is different we may have 2 li items or we may have 10 who knows.

what is the best approach to center a ul or a div that will change in width? i know to center a div or ul i would use following:

```
#name, ul {
 width:200px; /*set certain width */
 margin:0 auto; /* center div */
 display:block /* play friendly with the existing layout */
}
```

my problem is with the data the div may be 200px or beyond 200px, and as a result it would not truly be centered, since the div center alignment is based on width.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try  `#name, ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
}`

Comment: from my experience i would need a width to center a div or ul. in your example the lack of width breaks any alignment.

Comment: you gave not enough info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, is a way you can center a `ul` that has dynamic content length.

You can wrap the `ul` in a div and set the CSS property on the DIV as

```
.wrapper{
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center align the `ul` inside the `div` irrespective of the width of the div, you can see an example below:

Codepen Link http://codepen.io/nadirlaskar/pen/RKbBpM

```css
.wrapper{
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}

ul{
  background-color:red;
}

li{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2  is now large</li>  
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not solve the issue at hand. Not even close unfortunately

Comment: Check my updated answer, It will center `ul` irrespective of the width of the content of `ul`.

( link to code pen: http://codepen.io/nadirlaskar/pen/RKbBpM )

Comment: thank you so much! i've never come across this solution. you rock! moving this code to production!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Cheers!! I am glad to hear that :)